# How to prevent loading data by each request in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am profiling the database calls and I notice that we have a lot database calls per request. I think I can reduce the database calls by storing the person data (DTO) into a Session or cache.

We are using NHibernate and the problem is that the complete object graph for person is loaded each time we need a single property of the person. So I was wondering if there is a way to load the complete object graph once and then store it somewhere in memory so that not every request has to load the person object.

Is there some architectural best practice to accomplish this? Or are there some other best practices that deal with his kind of situations?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate offers a L2 cache that is valid for all ISession objects create from the same SessionFactory (that should be static). You can use a InMemory provider or even external providers such as AppFabric, SqlServer, Redis, etc.

I think this would be the simplest solution for you case, since you would only have to change the NHibernate configuration.

Some starting reference -> http://www.sharpcoder.co.uk/post/2012/01/04/NHibernateCachesAppFabric.aspx